# CMake on a C# project: Any CPU?

Tags: c#, cmake, csproj, platform

I have recently taken hold of a Windows project written in C#, and managed to create CMakeLists so that one can generate a solution on-the-fly and build it using Visual Studio.

This comes as a replacement for the legacy *.sln file that all developers were checking out from the repo. So far, so good. Now I would like to be more specific about the target platform and allow "Any CPU", just like the said legacy solution did. More precisely, I would like the *.csproj files to show:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'" Label="Configuration">
```

I have followed [this GitLab thread](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17521) but adding either `target_compile_options(MyProject PRIVATE "/platform:anycpu")` or `set(CMAKE_CSharp_FLAGS "/platform:anycpu")` only adds `<PlatformTarget>anycpu</PlatformTarget>` into the relevant PropertyGroup, rather than transforming the "Release|x64" to a "Release|AnyCPU":

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'" Label="Configuration">
    <PlatformTarget>anycpu</PlatformTarget>
```

The project has a main CMakeLists.txt which adds subdirectories (add_subdirectory). The sub-project CMakeLists are structured as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(MyProject VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES CSharp)


include(CSharpUtilities)

add_executable(MyProject...)

csharp_set_designer_cs_properties(...)
csharp_set_xaml_cs_properties(...)


target_compile_options(MyProject PRIVATE "/platform:anycpu" )

set_source_files_properties(...)
```

I am quite hung up on this as it has implications for TeamCity, which seems to be looking up specific pairs of {Configuration, Platform} directly by parsing the *.csproj files, and complaining if it cannot find "Release|AnyCPU".

Many thanks for any hints.